# Elasticsearch: count rows in a table

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a big table (15000 x 2000 entries). In this table, I need to count rows with certain properties like "all rows, that have a 1 or 2 in column 5 and a 0 in column 6". I will call this type of operation a count operation. For my use case, the count operation needs to be very fast, as I executing several hundreds of those count operations.

I tried to do so with elastic search, but the performance seems to be very bad (like 10 seconds for 180 count operations). I was wondering, if I am building my queries the wrong way, or if maybe Elasticsearch is the wrong technology to do so?

My queries are all of the same form. I create them with java, so it's kind of hard to post here, how they do look like but I do my best to explain

I build each single coun operation as a BoolQuery. For the example above it would be a query that looks similar to this (don't blame me if it's wrong, I cannot copy the correct query, as it is built in java):

```
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        "should" : [
          { "column 5" : "1" },
          { "column 5" : "2" }
        ],
        "should" : [
          { "column 6" : "0" }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
      ],
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
```

The many bool queries of this form are then grouped into a MultiSearchRequest. I use the option "fetchSource = false" to prevent Elasticsearch from loading the entities themselves.

Please tell me, if you need any further information, or if it is unclear, what I am trying to do!

Comment: What do you mean by 180 count operations? All are indexed? What kind of counts are you doing? Its very unclear. In your java part explanation, you are not syaung how are you executing each counts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i tried to reformulate it more clearly! Please tell me, if you have any further questions!

Comment: How many shards are there? How many indices are you querying? What's the resource capacity on a node? How many nodes are there? etc..

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem myself. For all with a similar question, here is how:

I changed the SearchSourceBuilder, so that it now uses a ValueCountAggregator. This one counts the values and allows me to set the SearchSourceBuilder.size() to 0. In this way I get rid of the hits themselves and retrieve only the aggregation values.

Requests that took 4 seconds before are now executed in less than 100ms.